# Nginx extract a value from a variable or any string

Tags: redirect, nginx

Is there an alternative of using If to extract a value from a variable in Nginx config files?

I.e

```
    if ($http_referer ~* (?<=url=)([\w-.]*)(?=/) ){
            set $proxied $1;
            rewrite (?<=/)(.+\.(css|jpg|png|gif|js)) http://$proxied/$1 redirect;

     }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. http://nginx.org/r/map

```
map $http_referer $proxied {
    default  example.com;
    "~*(?<=url=)(?<p>[\w-.]*)(?=/)" $p;
}
```

Comment: THanks that looks like this will do the trick, though what does the $p stand for ?

Comment: It's named capture: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html
since map doesn't support positional captures.

Comment: In your `if` example the `set $proxied $1;` directive is redundant. You could write `(?<=url=)(?<proxied>[\w-.]*)(?=/)`.

Comment: @VBart: `map` is [documented](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) to support positional captures as well

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu: The documentation is wrong, or at least highly misleading: see http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254538,254555

Comment: According to the documentation, map can only be performed in http context. Is there something like this that can be used in the location context?